# Problem with ACM bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, acm, acmart

I am writing a paper for an ACM journal. The problem is when I use the following commands:

```
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format} 
\bibliography{references}
```

the references appear without number. And when I replace “ACM-Reference-Format” with “acm” in the “\bibliographystyle” command, the references with URL loose their URLs. I'm wondering if anyone knows how I can solve this problem. My goal is to have a numbered reference list in which URLs do not disappear. I am working in Overleaf environment and use Mendeley to import my references to the Overleaf. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Did you check what the requirements of the journal are for the reference format? If the journal provides a LaTeX template/class/style file then you can probably find there what the required format is and which commands you need to get that style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

I'm assuming you use the `acmart` document class. If that's the case, the `ACM-Reference-Format` bibliography style should have no problems typesetting the numbers of bibliographic entries or their URL strings -- assuming the URL strings are stored in a field called `url`.

[image]

The much older `acm` bibliography style does not recognize the `url` field and hence simply ignores its contents.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@misc{w:19,
   author  = "Woody",
   title   = "Problem with {ACM} bibliography style",
   year    = 2019,
   url     = "https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474684/problem-with-acm-bibliography-style",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{acmart}
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}

\begin{document}
\cite{w:19}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

If you do *not* use the `acmart` document class but still wish to use the `ACM-Reference-Format` bibliography style, be sure to (a) load the `natbib` package with the option `numbers` and (b) either the `xurl` or the `url` package, the latter preferably with the options `hyphens` and `spaces`.